# How to skip part of the middlewares that are on the stack in Express js

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I am working on a backend of web application. And I have made a bunch of middlewares to be executed for each request that comes in -- [logging(before), authentication, Etag(Before), Nonce, httpRequest, Etag(after), logging(after)]. Now my problem is that, while processing each request, there are some special cases happen when the request should skip the rest of the middleware and just do logging. **I can do it the dump way just make all the middleware to check if certain condition has happened and if true just call `next()`, and otherwise process the request using the middleware. But I am wondering if there is a clever way to do this?**

Here is the snippet of the code I am currently using to configure the order of the middleware to be executed:

```
async.series(operations, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log('Something blew up!!!!!!');
            return next(err);
        }
        console.log('middleware get executed');
        // no errors so pass control back to express
        next();
    });
```

Where the "operations" variable is the list of middlewares I need to execute in order. I need to use the async.series() since I need to make the order the middleware configurable. **Is there a clever I can keep the order of middlewares configurable and fulfill my request as I said above?**

**EDIT：**

An example where I need to skip the rest of the middleware is **when authentication fails and write the statusCode to be "401 unauthorized",** then for the stack of the middleware [logging(before), authentication, Etag(Before), Nonce, httpRequest, Etag(after), logging(after)], I will jump from authentication to logging(after). and then that would be the end of the request.

Answer (score 1):

I had tried to understand your's concern

I am giving a snippet to execute middle ware function in row on the basis of need.

```
async.each(operations, function(operation, callback) {
   if(operation) {
       // if operation is required execute here

       callback();
   } else {
       // otherwise skip just to call callback() here
       callback();
   }



}, function(err){
    if( err ) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      next();
    }
});
```

all the operations in an array and to execute all one by one async provides [.each](https://github.com/caolan/async#each).

Its not mandatory to call each operation. You just skip by call callback() in else condition. I want to say that in if clause you can put your mandatory execution condition.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your reply, to be honest, I don't quite get your solution here. `function(operation, callback){  }` would be able to check the conditions after that particular middleware being executed? And with `async.each()`, even when the condition I need is true, and it jumps to callback, it will still come back to execute the rest of the middlewares on the operation stack?@Dineshaws